# Incoming packet does not delivered to socket

Tags: linux, iptables, socket, iproute

I have a vpn application that connects to vpn server with a tcp socket. I have marked tcp socket packets with `setsockopt` and `SO_MARK`. I can ping vpn gateway `ping 10.0.0.1` successfully.
Then I try to route my whole traffic through the vpn. I create a different table and add default gateway with `ip route add default via 10.0.0.1 dev tun0 table 200` and `ip rule add lookup 200`.
But then vpn's own packets start to go through vpn. I run `ip rule add fwmark 1234 lookup main` and vpn's own packets are excluded from vpn. I can see them with tcpdump going through `eth0` and vpn servers answering them.But incoming packets are not being delivered to tcp socket. Kernel seems to be dropping them. Why?

Comment: This is likely due to [reverse path filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_path_forwarding). Try [turning it off](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.kernel.rpf.html)